# Странное поведение ссылки в диве

Tags: html, z-index

Доброго дня всем.
Делаю коТ: в диве два дива, один поверх другого индексом.
 1. Если убрать картинку, то ссылка работает по ширине и высоте дива
 2. Если вставить картинку, то ссылка начинает работать только по тексту.
Почему такое происходит, картинка как-бы перекрывает линьк у дива, в свою очередь, текст "прорывается на верх" и работает линьк уже без ширины и высоты.

```
  <div id="div_name_01" style="position: absolute; left:10px; top:10px; width: 100px; height:100px; z-index:1; border:solid 1px #FF0000;">

     <div id="div_name_02" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left: 0px; width:100px; height:100px; text-align: center; font-size: 26px; color: #ed1c24; font-weight:bold; z-index:999; border:solid 1px #FF0000; cursor:pointer; display:block;" onclick="AlarmClick()">ТЕКСТ
     </div>

     <div style="position:absolute; top:0px; left: 0px; z-index:0;">
     <img src="01.jpg">
     </div>
  </div>
```

Всё ведь теоретически правильно.
картинка тоже 100х100 пихелей.
(Отладку делаю на IE9)

Answer (score 1):

Ослик как всегда в своем репертуаре. Все остальные браузеры одинаково отрабатывают.
Можно создать тот же дизайн, не делая страницу излишне дивной. По сути здесь бы хватило всего одного дива с текстом и картинкой как фон.
Вариант с двумя дивами, работающий в ослике:

```
 <div id="div_name_01" style="position: absolute; left:10px; top:10px; width: 100px; height:100px; z-index:0; border:solid 1px #FF0000;">

     <div id="div_name_02" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left: 0px; width:100px; height:100px; text-align: center; font-size: 26px; color: #ed1c24; font-weight:bold; z-index:2; border:solid 1px #FF0000; cursor:pointer; display:block; background-image:url(01.jpg)" onclick="alert(666);">ТЕКСТ
     </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Про засунуть картинку в background я первым делом подумал, но это значит сдаться перед осликом ;)  
Я хотел, вот именно что-бы по правилам ;)